# Problems running R from SQL Server

Tags: sql, r

I am running a standard piece of code from the MS SQL manual to test R functionality and am getting the error below. I'm thinking this is a setup issue of some kind since I am running code used as an example on the Microsoft site.

The error:

> STDERR message(s) from external script: During startup - warning message:
>   In setJsonDatabasePath(system.file("extdata/capabilities.json", bytecode version mismatch; using eval

The code (just to prove it's standard):

```
EXEC   sp_execute_external_script  
   @language = N'R'  
 , @script = N'iris_data <- iris;'
 , @input_data_1 = N''  
 , @output_data_1_name = N'iris_data'
 WITH RESULT SETS (("Sepal.Length" float not null,   
       "Sepal.Width" float not null,  
    "Petal.Length" float not null,   
    "Petal.Width" float not null, "Species" varchar(100)));
```

Note that a result set is returned even though the error is thrown.
I am the `dbowner` on the database this is being run from.
Here's the info regarding the database configuration:

```
Product:    Microsoft SOL Server Enterprise: Core-based Licensing  (64-bit)
Operating System:   Windows Server 2019 Datacenter (10.0)
Platform:   Windows
Version:    Windows 14.0.2027.2
Language:   English (United States)
Memory: 28672 MB
Processors:     4
Root Directory:     C:\Program Files\Microsoft SOL Server\MSSOL 14...
Server Collation:   SOL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
Is Clustered:   False
Is XTP Supported:   TRUE
Is HADR Enabled:    False
```